# Cumulative sum in sql, in case of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

TakenOn is a datetime column

With the procedure as

```
;WITH TBL AS
  (SELECT CONVERT(date,TakenOn) AS Date,
          COUNT(*) AS 'NewSubs'
   FROM Urls (NOLOCK)
   WHERE FId = 11
     AND (TakenOn >= @StartDate)
     AND (TakenOn <= @EndDate)
   GROUP BY CONVERT(date,TakenOn))
SELECT t1.Date, t1.NewSubs,
                SUM(t1.NewSubs) AS 'TotalSubs'
FROM TBL t1
INNER JOIN TBL t2 ON t1.Date >= t2.Date
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.NewSubs
```

the output is : //(which is wrong for me)

```
Date       NewSubs  TotalSubs
2014-09-19  2        2
2014-09-20  3        6
2014-09-21  1        3
2014-09-22  4        16
```

What should I change for the output to be

```
Date       NewSubs  TotalSubs
2014-09-19  2        2
2014-09-20  3        5
2014-09-21  1        6
2014-09-22  4        10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `SUM(t1.NewSubs) over(order by t1.Date)`

For example:

```
;WITH TBL AS
  (SELECT CONVERT(date,TakenOn) AS Date,
          COUNT(*) AS 'NewSubs'
   FROM Urls (NOLOCK)
   WHERE FId = 11
     AND (TakenOn >= @StartDate)
     AND (TakenOn <= @EndDate)
   GROUP BY CONVERT(date,TakenOn))
SELECT t1.Date, t1.NewSubs,
                SUM(t1.NewSubs) over(order by t1.Date) AS 'TotalSubs'
FROM TBL t1
INNER JOIN TBL t2 ON t1.Date >= t2.Date
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.NewSubs
```